# youtube-dl installed, but not found in dash or applications

Tags: 12.04

I have installed youtube-dl(program for downloading videos from youtube) successfully but I am not able to see it either in dash or among application folder. It is listed in software centre and synaptic packet manager. somebody suggest a way out..thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

Youtube-dl is run from the terminal. Open the terminal and type:

```
youtube-dl <URL>
```

You can also show a list of available video formats before you download the video, giving you a choice of different video qualities, by running the following command:

```
youtube-dl -F <URL>
```

Type `man youtube-dl` for information about how to use [`youtube-dl`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/youtube-dl) and options.

Answer (score 0):

There is also some nice documentation online:

youtube-dl Documentation
http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/documentation.html

As well have a look at the 'built-in' documentation from the command line by running:

```
youtube-dl --help
```

in a Terminal window and scrolling through the many, many options. My own practice is to convert this Terminal output to a readable text file as follows:

```
youtube-dl --help > youtube_dl_helpfile
```

Then you can read the resulting output file at your leisure with the text editor of your choice...

Answer (score 0):

You can use Youtube-dlG, a multi-platform GUI for youtube-dl. The GUI lets you download multiple videos at once, can automatically convert downloaded videos to audio, lets you select the video quality and more & u can find it from dash :P .See [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/385924/is-there-a-gui-for-youtube-dl) for more details.