# I have installed youtube-dl but I can not find out how to use it

Tags: downloaders

Hello I have downloaded youtube-dl through the terminal but I can not use it. I can't even find the icon for it on my screen. Help, please.

Answer (score 1):

This is a command line tool.  Open a terminal and input youtube-dl {url of the video you want to download} and hit enter.  It'll download the youtube video and put it in your home folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and after a while I decided to install Konqueror browser (it can be installed on any Ubuntu-based distro) and used some addon very similar with 'youtube-dl'. In Konqueror settings they call addons 'Services' I don't know why so you have to install youtube-dl or videotube-dl as a 'service' in Konqueror.

Or you can just use the solution provided by MrVaykadji above where he or she directed you to [this link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/318798/youtube-dl-installed-but-not-found-in-dash-or-applications).

But if you really want to install the best video downloader out there then you can search in Mozilla Firefox addons page for '[Flash Video Downloader - Full HD Download](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flash-video-downloader/)', it downloads pretty much anything from the web.